# Repeating an extra when using a Dragonfly CompoundRule

Tags: python, speech-recognition, python-dragonfly

Using [dragonfly2](https://dragonfly2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), the voice command framework, you can make a grammar like so:

```
chrome_rules = MappingRule(
    name='chrome',
    mapping={
        'down [<n>]': actions.Key('space:%(n)d'),
    },
    extras=[
        IntegerRef("n", 1, 100)
    ],
    defaults={
        "n": 1
    }
)
```

This lets me press space `n` times, where `n` is some integer. But what do I do if I want to use the same variable (`n`), multiple times in the same grammar? If I repeat it in the grammar, e.g. `'down <n> <n>'` and then say something like "down three four", Dragonfly will parse it correctly, but it will only execute the `actions.Key('space:%(n)d')` with `n=3`, using the first value of `n`. How can I get it to execute it 3 times, and then 4 times using the same variable?

Ideally I don't want to have to duplicate the variable `n`, in the extras and defaults, because that seems like redundant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Your `MappingRule` passes data to your `Action` (e.g. `Key`, `Text`) in the form of a dictionary, so it can only pass one value per extra. Your best bet right now is probably to create multiple extras.

---

This is a side-effect of the way dragonfly parses recognitions. I'll explain it first with `Action` objects, then we can break down why this happens at the `Rule` level.

When Dragonfly receives a recognition, it has to deconstruct it and extract any extras that occurred. The speech recognition engine itself has no trouble with multiple occurrances of the same extra, and it does pass that data to dragonfly, but dragonfly loses that information.

All `Action` objects are derived from `ActionBase`, and this is the method dragonfly calls when it wants to execute an `Action`:

```py
    def execute(self, data=None):
        self._log_exec.debug("Executing action: %s (%s)" % (self, data))
        try:
            if self._execute(data) == False:
                raise ActionError(str(self))
        except ActionError as e:
            self._log_exec.error("Execution failed: %s" % e)
            return False
        return True
```

This is how `Text` works, same with `Key`. It's not documented here, but `data` is a dictionary of extras mapped to values. For example:

```py
{
    "n":    "3",
    "text": "some recognized dictation",
}
```

See the issue? That means we can only communicate a single value per extra. Even if we combine multiple actions, we have the same problem. For example:

```py
{
    "down <n> <n>": Key("%(n)d") + Text("%(n)d"),
}
```

Under the hood, these two actions are combined into an `ActionSeries` object - a single action. It exposes the same `execute` interface. One series of actions, one `data` dict.

Note that this doesn't happen with compound rules, even if each underlying rule shares an extra with the same name. That's because `data` is decoded & passed *per-rule*. Each rule passes a different `data` dict to the `Action` it wishes to execute.

---

If you're curious where we lose the second extra, we can navigate up the call chain.

Each rule has a `process_recognition` method. This is the method that's called when a recognition occurs. It takes the current rule's `node` and processes it. This `node` might be a tree of rules, or it could be something lower-level, like an `Action`. Let's look at the implementation in `MappingRule`:

```py
    def process_recognition(self, node):
        """
            Process a recognition of this rule.

            This method is called by the containing Grammar when this
            rule is recognized.  This method collects information about
            the recognition and then calls *self._process_recognition*.

            - *node* -- The root node of the recognition parse tree.
        """
        # Prepare *extras* dict for passing to _process_recognition().
        extras = {
                  "_grammar":  self.grammar,
                  "_rule":     self,
                  "_node":     node,
                 }
        extras.update(self._defaults)
        for name, element in self._extras.items():
            extra_node = node.get_child_by_name(name, shallow=True)
            if extra_node:
                extras[name] = extra_node.value()
            elif element.has_default():
                extras[name] = element.default

        # Call the method to do the actual processing.
        self._process_recognition(node, extras)
```

I'm going to skip some complexity - the `extras` variable you see here is an early form of the `data` dictionary. See where we lose the value?

```py
extra_node = node.get_child_by_name(name, shallow=True)
```

Which looks like:

```py
    def get_child_by_name(self, name, shallow=False):
        """Get one node below this node with the given name."""
        for child in self.children:
            if child.name:
                if child.name == name:
                    return child
                if shallow:
                    # If shallow, don't look past named children.
                    continue
            match = child.get_child_by_name(name, shallow)
            if match:
                return match
        return None
```

So, you see the issue. Dragonfly tries to extract one value for each extra, and it gets the first one. Then, it stuffs that value into a dictionary and passes it down to `Action`. Additional occurrences are lost.